# Dataweave transformation array of elements into string

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

Can anyone kindly provide the DataWeave logic for the below output structure based on the input data(Items of the array object).

Input Data

```
{
    "Items": [{
        "name": "Document",
        "value": ["Representative", "Manager"]
    }, {
        "name": "Product",
        "value": ["Sales", "Price"]
    }]
}
```

Output data:

```
^(+Document:"Representative" +Document:"Manager") ^(+Product:"Sales" +Product:"Price")
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is by using a combination of `map` function and `joinBy`

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
payload.Items 
    map ((item, index) -> "^(" ++ 
        (item.value 
            map ((value, index) -> '+$(item.name):"$(value)"') 
            joinBy  " ") 
        ++ ")"
    )
joinBy  " "
```